# Why are simple operations on pandas.DataFrames so slow compared to the same operations on numpy.ndarrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Why are operations on `pandas.DataFrame`s so slow?! Look at the following examples.

#### Measurement:

- Create a `numpy.ndarray` populated with random floating point numbers
- Create a `pandas.DataFrame` populated with the same numpy array

The I measure the time of the following operations

1. For the `numpy.ndarray`

   - Take the sum along the 0-axis
   - Take the sum along the 1-axis
2. For the `pandas.DataFrame`

   - Take the sum along the 0-axis
   - Take the sum along the 1-axis
3. For the `pandas.DataFrame.values -> np.ndarray`

   - Take the sum along the 0-axis
   - Take the sum along the 1-axis

#### Observations

- Summing over `numpy.ndarrays' is much faster then operating on`pandas.DataFrames`.
- This is even true, if the `pd.DataFrame` does not contain only floating point numbers and has nothing special attached (MultiIndex or whatever).
- Operations on `numpy.ndarray` are about 7 to 10 times faster.

#### Questions

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can this be optimized?
3. Is `pandas` not able to call or pass through `numpy`s' operations?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

```py
n = 50000
m = 5000
array = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (n, m))
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(array)
```

#### Numpy

```py
%%timeit
array.sum(axis=0)
```

```
206 ms ± 3.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
%%timeit
array.sum(axis=1)
```

```
233 ms ± 33.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Pandas

```py
%%timeit
dataframe.sum(axis=0)
```

```
1.65 s ± 14.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
%%timeit
dataframe.sum(axis=1)
```

```
1.74 s ± 15.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### Pandas without Pandas

Let's operate on the values alone ...

```py
%%timeit
dataframe.values.sum(axis=0)
```

```
206 ms ± 7.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
%%timeit
dataframe.values.sum(axis=1)
```

```
181 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: [Sofia Heisler from pycon2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN5d490_KKk) states *Like Pandas, NumPy operates on array objects (referred to as ndarrays); however, it leaves out a lot of overhead incurred by operations on Pandas series, such as indexing, data type checking, etc. As a result, operations on NumPy arrays can be significantly faster than operations on Pandas series.*

Comment: [Blog post of Sofia Heisler](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

Comment: [Another blog post comparing *Numpy* and *Pandas*](https://penandpants.com/2014/09/05/performance-of-pandas-series-vs-numpy-arrays/)

Comment: @Sofia: Thanks, for your answers but why does it do so, if the dataframe is such a simple one? It does not have mixed data types. I would expect, that in this case I get only some overhead which scales away with larger matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas uses numpy as its underlying data containers, but provide much more features. A DataFrame contains a collection of 1D numpy arrays of possibly different dtypes, along with 2 Index (one for the rows and one for the columns). Those index can even be of MultiIndex types.

All this comes at a performance cost.

The good news is that you can directly process the underlying numpy arrays at numpy level for additional performance if you do not need the fancy indexing of pandas.

Comment: Dear Serge, I think what you say is not true, pandas (at least for version 0.23.4) does not store data in a collection of 1d numpy arrays. The data are always 2d (blocks) for a given datatype like float64. Or am I wrong? I used pandas especially because of its MultiIndex and its grouping capabilities for some multidimensional modelling. Although, pandas is very slow on grouping and aggregation, you can tweak it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274882/how-to-keep-major-order-when-copying-or-groupby-ing-a-pandas-dataframe/61498345#61498345 for example.

Comment: @thomas. Serge is correct that pandas does a lot of bookkeeping that slows insert and removal operations.  Even retrieval of a value requires twice as much work bc pandas has to recieve the request and address it to the numpy object.  I am interested in your thought that dataframes are collections of like typed columns in arrays. I doubt this, but am willing to keep reading the source code if you give us a hint where you found that.